# Convert form.RenderControl() value to xml Well Formed

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

On ASP.NET, how do I convert the output from `form1.RenderControl()` to well-formed xml?

Answer (score 0):

This MSDN page has lots of helpful information on this problem.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc57y7e.aspx